# Fill an array and then call a function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, completionhandler

In completion of a fetch data, I receive a data item one by one. I want to append this item in an array and then call data, how can I do that? how I can tell to the function to wait untill all data append to the array - and the number of data is different.

```
self?.dataModel.fetchExportCSV(id: id, completion: { [weak self] in
    switch $0 {
      case .success(let data):
          var arryData: [exportVO] = []
          arryData.append(data)

          //this is the fucntion that should be called after all the data are append to the array
          createCSV(data: arryData)
```

Comment: Use `DispatchGroup` or `Semaphores`

Comment: could you show me one example

Comment: Are you saying your completion handler gets called multiple times or that you call `fetchExportCSV` multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    self?.dataModel.fetchExportCSV(id: id, completion: { [weak self] in
        let dGroup = DispatchGroup()

      switch $0 {
        case .success(let data):
          dGroup.enter()
          var arryData: [exportVO] = []
          arryData.append(data)
          dGroup.leave()
      }

     //after switch case
      dGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            createCSV(data: arryData)
      }
    }
```

add the .enter() .leave() to all the cases in switch

[More Info](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/a-deep-dive-into-grand-central-dispatch-in-swift/)

[Dispatch group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

[DispatchSemaphore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore)